# Fail loading a ML PySpark model

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I have a couple of regression models that I cannot load.
This is the Spark init:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext
from pyspark.ml.regression import DecisionTreeRegressor

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Linear Regression Model") \
    .config('spark.executor.cores','2') \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "5gb") \
    .master("local[*]") \
    .getOrCreate() 

sc = spark.sparkContext
```

Here is the model fitting and saving it succesfully:

```
# Decision Tree Regression
decisionTree = DecisionTreeRegressor(featuresCol = "Features", labelCol = "SalePrice", maxDepth = 15, maxBins = 32)
decisionTreeModel = decisionTree.fit(train_vector)

import os

decisionTreeModel.save(os.path.join(".", 'decisionTreeModel'))
```

But when I load it back:

```
persistedModel = DecisionTreeRegressor.load("decisionTreeModel")
```

I get this ERROR:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1201.load.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.spark.ml.regression.DecisionTreeRegressionModel.<init>(java.lang.String)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.DefaultParamsReader.load(ReadWrite.scala:468)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Does anybody knows how to load a PySpark Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is not very helpful, but I think the correct way to load the model back is to call the `load` method of the model, not of the estimator. The model is fitted to the data already, which is different from the estimator, which only contains the settings/parameters, but is not fitted.

So you can try this:

```
from pyspark.ml.regression import DecisionTreeRegressionModel

persistedModel = DecisionTreeRegressionModel.load("decisionTreeModel")
```

For your information, here's a comparison of loading the estimator vs loading the model:

```
from pyspark.ml.regression import DecisionTreeRegressor, DecisionTreeRegressionModel

decisionTree = DecisionTreeRegressor(featuresCol = "Features", labelCol = "SalePrice", maxDepth = 15, maxBins = 32)
decisionTree.save('tree')
persistedEstimator = DecisionTreeRegressor.load('tree')

decisionTreeModel = decisionTree.fit(df)
decisionTreeModel.save('model')
persistedModel = DecisionTreeRegressionModel.load('model')
```